# Import "flask_mysqldb" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

Uhh, well I get this error

> Import "flask_mysqldb" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)

And I don't really know if I'm missing something because when I try to install stuff it says "requirement already fulfilled" and I'm panicking because I don't know what I'm doing wrong. This is the actual code I'm working with but I can't use anything related to databases because the 2nd line doesn't work:

`from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash`

`from flask_mysqldb import MySQL`

Comment: try running pip freeze , this should show you what packages you have in the current conext installed

Comment: Also in regards to the question you should be more specific, what env you are in, is it some IDE or command line. Are you using virtualenv or not. WHat commands you used to try to install the packages.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have installed the package into the environment which you have selected.

You can get which python interpreter you are using from the bottom-left on the VSCode:

[image]

And which pip you are using in the terminal with the command of `pip --version`.

Normally, after you select the python interpreter in the VSCode, you should create a new terminal with the shortcut of **Ctrl+Shift+`**, then you can install the package into the environment which you have selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing the dependency via `pip`:

```
pip install flask_mysqldb
```

Answer (score -1):

This was a while back but I'm vaguely sure it was an error that had to do with the enviroment and where I had stuff saved.

So if anyone has the same question I'd say track your program files and stuff.

Sorry I'm vague.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).